# Overriding the sprites in a Animation clip

Tags: unity, animation

Right now we are in the process of adding seasonal content to our game. I would like to know of a way to override animation clips. Specifically I want to change the sprites being show at each key-frame. Looking from the text of a animation clip I found the following :

```
 m_PPtrCurves:
  - curve:
    - time: 0
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - time: 0.6
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - time: 0.6666667
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - time: 1.2333333
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - time: 2.0001667
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - time: 2.05
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - time: 3.1166666
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 502fc97a961e4424ea008c0e546c83ef, type: 3}
    - time: 3.45
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    attribute: m_Sprite
```

This corresponds to the key frames and amount of sprites in the animation clip but I have no idea from where to get the data for the new sprites. I'm guessing the guid is a hashed path to the png files. can someone  explain where to find this data so I can write myself a neat little parser to do the job?

Comment: Presumably you looked at the .meta files Unity creates for each imported asset? The GUIDs are in there.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/animationclip-problems.218106/#post-1669347

This helped me a little.

You can get serialized Properties and use the `FindPropertyRelative` function to find the data that you want to modify. Like `m_PPtrCurves` and in there `attribute` and `curve`.

`InsertArrayElementAtIndex` combined with `ApplyModifiedProperties` can make new array elements